# Is there any advantage of Web API over WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have experience in developing Restful web service using WCF. For the next project, I am considering Web API because that is the latest technology.

During my search, I found that an important reason for Web API recommendation is that it is Restful and can be accessed by HTTP protocol.

But we can also use WCF to create a restful web service that can be consumed even by mobile devices. I understand that to create a restful service using WCF, there is extra configuration involved, but besides that are there any other reasons for preferring Web API over WCF?

In other words, does Web API provide an exact subset of WCF functionality, or is there something you can do with Web API that you cannot do with a WCF service exposed as restful?

Comment: See this Microsoft article [WCF and ASP.NET Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172.aspx)

Comment: After go through the comparision between WCF and Web Api from that page, for me it seems WCF is more advanced than Web Api, as WCF can be configured as Restful or Soap service, and many other benefit. I have to learn and switch to Web Api if it has any advantage over WCF such as performance and so on. Iam comparing WCF Rest Service that can return json, but not WCF Soap Service with Web Api. Thanks.

Comment: @TrevorPilley - the MSDN article suggests in the last paragraph that "the support for REST in ASP.NET Web API is more complete", but so far I have never found anything that Web API has which WCF doesn't. As of now it appears that Web API is truly a subset. I want to have a reason to choose Web API over WCF, but whenever I get pushback it's hard to argue with "But what if someone wants to use a binding other than REST in the future?"

Comment: Questions of a rather "abstract" nature, such as this one, may be considered somewhat off-topic on SO, yet possibly well-suited for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Dev-iL when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Thank you for adding that clarification. It was not my intention to have the OP create the same question on another site.. Rather, to suggest a more fitting place for similar questions in the future. Unfortunately, this post is too old to migrate, so there's nothing more constructive for me to do than to suggest the above.